# who could explain more about the compare function in priority queue C++

Tags: c++, compare, priority-queue

we could define operator < but always people seem to use a class define a operator ()?

how does this exactly work.

I have learned generic thing like this in C before,  at that time, we use a pointer to a function.

What is the difference?

Comment: Class member function calls can be inlined. Function pointers always require indirection.

Comment: @KerrekSB Do they? I'd assume `std::sort(b, e, &myCompare)` could inline the calls to `myCompare` if its definition is available.

Comment: @Angew: Why not try it and tell us what you find?

Comment: @KerrekSB **1.** Unfortunately, I don't know assembly at all, so it's next to impossible for me to check. **2.** While getting an 'inlined' result would mean "yes, it can," a 'not inlined' result would just mean "this compiler with these settings didn't inline it in this time." Do you have a link where I could learn more of why no inlining is possible in this case?

Comment: I am still confused why we send a struct to it rather than a function pointer by defining a cmp function. In the struct, it seems that we overload the operator (), why?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want your code to contain the least amount of surprises.

Let's say you have a `std::priority_queue<T> pq` for your class `T`. Is `T` a class for which a natural ordering exists? If so, define an `operator <` for it. Do you want `pq` to be prioritised based on this ordering? If so, just let it use the `operator <` and you're done.

However, quite often, `T` is a class with no intrinsic notion of ordering. Imagine a class `Employee` storing `name`, `startingDate` and `salary`. There is no universal ordering - given two employees, it's not clear which one is `<` than the other.

At the same time, you may want a `std::priority_queue<Employee>` based on who earns the most. Or the least. Or who's with the company the longest. Therefore, you'll use specific comparators for these.

In a way, the priority queue comparator and `operator <` are independent concepts. If you have a naturally orderable class, give it `operator <`. If you want a priority queue, give it an appropriate predicate. If that predicate happens to be `operator <`, just let it use that.

As to why to use a class with `operator()` instead of a pointer to function, I'd say the primary reason is typing and construction. *Class* templates which use comparators (such as `std::priority_queue` or `std::map`) have the *type* of the comparator as their template parameter (they have no other option). Then, when constructing the container, you have two options: provide an object of the comparator type, or let the class create one by default construction.

When the type of the comparator is a class (with a default constructor, which is normally present for these functor classes), the constructor of `std::priority_queue` can default-construct it and work. If you use a function pointer, the type of the queue will be e.g. `std::priority_queue<T, SomeContainer, bool (*)(const T&, constT&)>`, and you will have to pass an appropriate function pointer to each queue you create.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I still do not know why we define cpm function as a class overload ()

Comment: @user3341953 I've added the info into the answer (it wasn't clear to me from your question's wording that you're after `operator()` vs. function pointer; it looked more like `operator <` vs. comparator).